# Can't find the DTS pipeline component to reference in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: ssis, components

I haven't written any custom SSIS components in a few years and am having problems trying to do one currently. I have the following installed:

VS 2019, SQL Server 2017, SSDT.

I have created a project in VS and when I try to find the component containing the SSIS dts pipeline stuff, it is not in the list. I do see a plethora of other SSIS transforms, sources, and destinations type libraries though.

Any ides on what I am missing?

Comment: To be clear, you want to create a new component that then appears in the VS SSIS Toolbox, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do, using C# If have done them in the past, it has just been a few years and either things changed or I have forgotten more than I thought :-) Google has been no help so far as the places I have found with tutorials seem to be outdated as I try them and I don't find the PipelineComponent anywhere

Comment: I did a little more searching and found that the DTS pipeline is actually found in `Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost.dll`, which can be found in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost\v4.0_1*.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91`. I had four different folders under  `..\Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost`. They probably correspond to different versions of the .NET Framework.